# R How to use Recommender System for columns with only 1's?

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to recommend movies (M1, M2, ...) for users (U1, U2, ...).

I'm using the R package recommenderlab. How do I use it correctly?
The model seems to work fine when the data is spread out but fails when all the ratings are 1. Here, the program simply returns cols with NA values in order. Do the ratings need to have a common scale? I've gone through [forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876272/building-a-user-based-collaborative-filtering-recommendation-system-in-r) and [R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf) already.

```
 #Building dataframe vector by vector
    v1 <- c(NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA)
    v2 <- c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA)    
    v3 <- c(1, 3, NA, 1, 1, 2, 9, NA, NA, NA)
    v4 <- c(NA, 2, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1)
    v5 <- c(23, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    df <- rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
    colnames(df) <- c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10")
    rownames(df) <- c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "U5")
>   df
   M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10
U1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  1 NA  1  NA
U2  1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1  NA
U3  1  3 NA  1  1  2  9 NA NA  NA
U4 NA  2  1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA   1
U5 23  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  NA

    #Generating recommendations
    recobuilder <- as(df, "realRatingMatrix")
    rec <- Recommender(recobuilder, method = "UBCF") #Building a recommender model with User-based CF from dataframe df
    pre <- predict(rec, recobuilder[1, ], n = 2)
    as(pre, "list")
```

Output for User 3:

```
$U3
[1] "M8" "M9" "M3"
```

So, it works correctly for user 3 as movies M8, M9 and M3 are recommended to him.

Output for User 1:

```
$U1
[1] "M1" "M4" "M5"
```

But it doesn't work correctly for user 1 as the movies recommended to him are just the cols. with NAs. in order. (M1, M4 and M5)

I expect something more along the lines of "M4" "M10" "M8" – true 'recommendations' as opposed to printing of cols. with NAs.

Please tell me how to do away with this discrepancy. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!